# "Interesting" Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Well, here's a question i myself made up and  i thought it's interesting if i share it with everyone.
We call a sequence of natural numbers (for example $a$) **Interesting** if (all three must be true):

1. It was a strictly increasing sequence
2. It had an  **even** number of items
3. All of the following inequalities were true: $a_1a_{2n}<a_2a_{2n-1}<...<a_na_{n+1}$ (Where $a_{2n}$ is the last number in the sequence)

Well, now the questions:

1. If we consider an even amount of prime numbers a sequence, are they Interesting?
    In the other words, is for any natural number $n>1$, $p_1p_{2n}<p_2p_{2n-1}<...<p_np_{n+1} $(Where $p_n $is the $n$'th prime number.)
2. Is there any real number $k$ so that if for any number in the sequence (for example $a_i$), we had $ka_i>a_{i+1}$, then we could assure that our sequence is Interesting?

Now my own works towards the questions:
For the first question i haven't really done anything, except giving some examples which all came true.
For the second question, i've given a counterexample for $k=2$; Consider the sequence: $2, 3, 5, 9, 16, 23$
Here we have $2a_i>a_{i+1}$ but $2*23=46<3*16=48>5*9=45$ which is probably not the thing we want. This also shows that if such number ($k$) exists, it should be smaller than $2$.
We also know that $k>1$ because if it was not, the sequence would not be strictly increasing.
So if $k$ exists, $2>k>1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $k>1$, find $n$ with $1+\frac 1n<k$. Then consider $a_1=n^3$, $a_2=n^2(n+1)$, $a_3=n(n+1)^2$, $a_4=(n+1)^3$. Then this is a strictly increasing seqeucen of integers with $a_{i+1}<ka_i$, but $a_1a_4=a_2a_3$, so it is not interesting. (By slightly modifying this seqeucen, you can get $a_1a_4>a_2a_3$ if you like)

Comment: What if our condition was "non-strictly increasing"? will such a $k$ exist?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your first question is no. Consider the set of primes $\{2,3,...,43\}$. Then we have $11*29=319$ and $13*23=299$.

Comment: Thank you, hard counterexample to find out by the way :)

Comment: Actually, looking at $43$ for someting somehow quaratic in primes may not be *too* far fetched.